# How to fix this error:- Unable to convert string ACTL6AS5 to float error in python

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, runtime-error

I am looking for support and advice on how to fix this error:- "**couldn't convert string ACTL6AS5 to float"** in python. Please give me a solution with example as I am new to python programming.

Error after running the code will be added here soon!

```
#Using the Standard Scaler Model for standardisation of dataset
  scaling=StandardScaler()

  scaling.fit_transform(Combined_data_df)[['features']]

  ValueError    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-bf55a81dd31a> in <module>
----> 1 scaling.fit_transform(Combined_data_df)[['features']]

**ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'ACTL6AS5'**
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please share the lines of code or script that is causing the error.

Comment: Can I share it in a new question Grismar

Comment: Why not edit this question?

Comment: You can edit this question and add the code - you can enclose it in triple backticks ``` if you want it to look nice like code

Comment: Code will be added here soon which is throwing an error and question will be edited

Comment: I don't see why you're even asking.  It's clear that the string `'ACTL6AS5'` isn't a valid number.

Comment: I have tried the answer 1 of try and expect before and it didn't work. Are there any other ways to solve this issue as it is badly affecting my work? Please refer to my answer 2 below

Comment: Grismar - I have added the lines of code which are causing the error at my first question (given above)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little incomplete...
if you take some input from the user and then convert it to string then probably the user input is not convertible like if you are trying to convert 'a' into float which can cause an error like this...

```
try:
    miles = float(input("How many distance you traveled"))
except:
    print("Please type in a number!")
```

this is called error handling user inputs something that is not convertible into float it'll tell the user to input a right value

Comment: The lines of code throwing the error is shared in the first question (see at the top of the page)

Comment: I don't know about ACTL6AS5 not even google gives me something special but I'm talking about usual errors that occur during conversion from int to string

Comment: I suggest to look the value you are trying to convert, is that really convertible...I mean 'abc' can't be convert to a number but '123' can convert to 123