# Unable to parse string "ACTL6AS5" at position 0

Tags: python, parse-error

This is another error I am getting:-
**Unable to parse string "ACTL6AS5" at position 0**

What is meant by this error?

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric()

ValueError: **Unable to parse string "ACTL6AS5"**

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-c08b0b717a59> in <module>
----> 1 Combined_data_df["features"] = Combined_data_df ["features"].apply(pd.to_numeric)

I have attempted to fix it like this:- 

#Trying to fix error 'unable to parse string 'ACTL6A_S5' at position 0
print (Combined_data_df[pd.to_numeric(Combined_data_df.features, errors='coerce').isnull()])
```

Is this the right fix?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't convert a `string` with `letters` to `numeric`, but yes you can `coerce` them to be `NaN`.

Comment: You can't convert a string with letters to numeric. What can I do to fix this?                   
Please refer to this discussion for more information - (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70357924/how-to-fix-this-error-unable-to-convert-string-actl6as5-to-float-error-in-pyth)